# Excel: Trying to add a single point to a line graph

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a graph with a horizontal axis of time, the vertical axis is a target percentage of stock in a storage tank that descend at a steady rate, eventually reaching zero, I'm trying to add a single point to indicate the current level and at the current time. I've tried playing around with the NOW() function but can't seem to get this to work

Edit: Maybe I didn't explain myself well. I have a spreadsheet that pulls data from an external source (level of tank as percentage and flow out of the tank) with this info I have calculated the downward slope of that level over time, the operator would consult this tool when he is required to have the tank empty for a certain time (for example he would enter a time of 18:00 for the tank to be empty and then look at the calculated percentage at 14:00 to see what percentage he would need to be at to ensure the tank is empty by 18:00) What I have done so far is plotted this line on a graph which is simple but I would like to plot a single point to indicate the current level (y axis) at the current time (x axis) so the operator has a visual reference as well as a raw list of numbers. Everything in this spreadsheet is automatically calculated or pulled from and external source except for a single time entered by the operator

Edit: got it all working, the user still enters only a time, then excel adds the date based on whether or not the time entered is in the past (adds tomorrow's date) or in the future (adds today's date) that's sounds weird now that I've typed it out but it works, thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

In order to **DRAW** a line you need at least two data points. If you want to plot just **ONE** data point you need to format the series as line with markers.

Edit: Use a formula to look up the current level from the data, then add that as a series to your existing chart. Use an XY Scatter chart instead of a line chart, then the current reading will be placed in the correct position on the X axis. The screenshot shows a scatter chart with a line for the projected level and a series formatted with markers for the last reading.

[image]

EDIT 2: It's hard to troubleshoot a chart long distance. Format the times as General, so they show as numbers. They should all be less than 1. Create an XY chart with these on the X axis. Set the major interval to 0.0416666666666667, which is 1 hour. Format the X axis numbers to link to data source and set the format of the data back to time values. If that does not help, it is likely that something is off with your source data.

Comment: Just added some info to my initial post, might clarify

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: That's basically what I've tried but I'm running into huge issues with time showing up on the x axis correctly on a scatter chart, my data is layed out exactly how you have it in your example but for some reason the x axis only shows 0:00 all the way across and the level percentages populate as a line straight up and down. So I guess my question is how the heck do you format the time correctly. My times are all produced through a formula creating a list of times at 15 min intervals, I hope that isn't the problem

Comment: What's the formula for your times? Is the output really a time value?

Comment: Well I was working off an existing formula that probably isn't the best way of doing it. There is a hidden cell in the spreadsheet that contains 0:15, lets say the user enters a time of 11:30 it would subtract 0:15 from it giving 11:15, 11:00 and so on as far as I know the output of this should be a valid time (it's formatted as time in the format options)

Comment: I added a suggestion to troubleshoot your chart. If you are sure the values are time values, you may want to start over with a new chart from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for all your help I'll play around with it next time im at work

Comment: Alright that much is working now, I changed =Now() to =MOD(NOW(),1) and the graph is working, my only problem now is handling different days, let's say it's 7pm and the grade change is at 1am the following morning, everything breaks because of the way I populated the list of times

Comment: Use full date/time values for the underlying data. Set the chart X axis to show a custom number format that displays the time values only. That will give you the desired result. You may need to ringfence min and max of the X axis. Type the desired start and end into worksheet cells as date/time values, then format to General to see what numbers you need for the axis settings.